# Расширение класса CSS - это возможно?

Tags: html, css, классы

Собственно, как можно, если вообще можно, создать новый класс CSS-стиля на основе старого, так, чтобы старый сохранился?

Допустим, есть вот такой код:

```css
.block {
  border: #000 groove 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Как расширить класс `.block`, например, добавив в него свойство `max-width:40%`?

**Спасибо.**

Comment: Если хочется работать с CSS таким образом, можно юзать [SASS](sass-lang.com). Там есть такая плюшка как `@extend`.

Comment: Или [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). Можно даже без серверной части:

    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less">
    <script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @Asen вы неправильно поставили вопрос поэтому получили неверные ответы! Ваш вопрос должен звучать так:
>Как задать несколько классов одному html элементу?
Пожалуйста отредактируйте вопрос чтобы последующие посетители ХэшКод увидив аш вопрос и ответы на него получили адекватное понимание классов css

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[[@Asen](/users/5040/asen)](/users/5040/asen), а что мешает добавить второй класс для элемента, в котором будут дополнения к первому?

```
.block{border:#000 groove 3px;}
.block_add{max-width:40%;}

<div class="block block_add"></div>
```

Comment: по-моему самое адекватное решение

Comment: Кстати, да. Я почему-то не задумывался о таком варианте. Спасибо.

Answer (score 7):

Просто дописать нужные селекторы:

```
.block{border:#000 groove 3px;}
/*Тут всё что хотите или ничего*/
.block{max-width:40%;}
```

В итоге получится:

```
.block{
border:#000 groove 3px;
max-width:40%;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но хочется именно создать новый класс на основе старого, так, чтобы старый сохранился.

Answer (score 2):

можно воспользоваться такой вставкой.

```
<style>
.block{
   max-width:40%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: О, спасибо. Вот это, кажется, то, что нужно, несмотря на то, что новый класс по сути создается виртуально, т.е как-бы нету.

Comment: Но это даст тот же результат что и в коде моего ответа!